# Can we use .Net Native as an alternative for developing Universal C# Application?

Tags: .net, xamarin

We are developing cross platform applications using C# and Xamarin. We are more interested to use a complete Microsoft based solution for developing our Universal Applications. Can .Net Native be that solution?

Thanks, Ravi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got a few things confused here.

.Net Native is about producing a file that is natively executable on the target real machine - an Intel CPU, for instance. All of the bits that make up the .Net VM in that executable file are packed into it and natively compiled.

However, all that gets you is the ability to run native machine code.

Second is how to interface with the operating system and userland environment of the machine you're running on. At the bottom *something* has to implement, say, the `Socket` class. On Windows, the Microsoft .Net framework uses Win32 to implement the Socket class. On Linux/Mac/*BSD, the .Net framework implemented in Mono etc use the posix socket API provided by the operating system.

How do you draw to the screen in Windows? GDI, GDI+, Direct2d, etc.

How do you draw to the screen in Linux/? X Windows. In OS X? Quartz. No amount of .Net compiler magic is going to automatically make that work for you.

.Net Native makes it so that you can have statically linked executables. But you still need an implementation of the .Net framework for the platform that you're running on. This is where Mono, Xamarin, etc, step in.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation